# Can you say which Haskell record instance you are using without repeating it each time you use a field?

Tags: haskell

I recently created a `Config` record type which contains data/functions which are used throughout my application. For example, let's say it's

```
data Config m u = Config
    { issuer       :: Text
    , loadUser     :: LoadUser m u
    , authenticate :: Authenticate m
    }
```

and I have another function which actually creates the application from the configuration:

```
buildServer :: Config -> m Server
buildServer cfg = ...
```

Now every time I use those record fields I have to explicitly apply them to `cfg` to get what I want:

```
    let someFunction = doSomething (issuer cfg) (loadUser cfg) (authenticate cfg)
```

Previously I was just creating the functions in the same scope (without the configuration data type), so this was just:

```
    let someFunction = doSomething issuer loadUser authenticate
```

Is there some way I can say "when I refer to these record fields, they all apply to this instance" in a block of code, rather than having to repeat it every time? I remember coming across something like this in the past, but can't find it now, and I could be wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, with the [`RecordWildCards`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#record-wildcards) extension:

```
buildServer (Config {..}) =
    let someFunction = doSomething issuer loadUser authenticate
    in undefined
```

Comment: @LukeTaylor Be mindful of Cubic's answer.  While it doesn't reduce typing, it does allow you to make composable combinators: `action1 = something1 <$> issuer <*> loadUser`; `action2 = something2 <$> authenticate <*> loadUser`; `action3 = something3 <$> action1 <*> action2`.

Answer (score 7):

Without any syntax extensions, you can simply use the `Applicative` instance of the function arrow for a similar effect:

```
someFunction = doSomething <$> 
               issuer <*>
               loadUser <*>
               authenticate $ cfg

-- or

someFunction' = liftA3 doSomething issuer loadUser authenticate cfg
```

although that's of course not really a whole lot shorter.

Comment: You end up trading 6 characters per field (3 for `cfg`, then `"() "`) for 4 characters (` <$>` or ` <*>`, note spaces) per field, plus the additional 6 characters of ` $ cfg`.  For 3 fields, this means 6*3=18 characters vs 3*4+6=18 characters.  There's literally no savings in number of characters typed in this case, but for 4 fields you end up with 24 vs 22 characters.  For replacing `cfg` with just `c`, you'd end up with 4*3=12 vs 3*4+4=16, and it'll never actually be less typing. However, I will point out that the applicative style is more reusable and composable, which is a clear advantage.

Comment: This is a nice idea, and while I'm now aware that `(->) `is an instance of Applicative (which a while back would have been "whoosh"), it's still something I have to make an effort to think about each time it comes up. Also the [real functions which I'm refactoring](https://github.com/tekul/broch/blob/3c896e2e8b5adb2b89ac220d7920fde06c40928b/Broch/Server.hs#L81) are a lot messier in practice, so I'm not sure how useful this would be in practice.